# How to enforce one-and-only-one concurrent logon per user with Oracle SSO?

Tags: oracle, single-sign-on

OK, the auditors have come knocking and I know one of their standard "exposures" is if your application allows concurrent logons by the same user.

Let's put aside the quantification of that risk for a minute...

The application I'm working with uses Oracle SSO for managing authentication, and as far as I know, it does not have an out-of-the-box solution for this.

I'm looking for advice - either a way that the standard product can be made to support this requirement, or the most maintainable, unintrusive customisation to do the same.

Appreciate any thoughts on the matter...

Comment: Have you written you own app and registered it with SSO, or are you using an Oracle App (e.g. Portal)?

Comment: Both actually ... Portal, some custom J2EE apps, and Oracle Apps

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the SSO part, you would add the user to a profile that limits the number of active sessions.

```
ALTER PROFILE app_user LIMIT SESSIONS_PER_USER 1;
```

I don't know what SSO adds to this.

Comment: Don't think that will work in my case, since the mid-tier does proxy authentication to the database? Each actual user doesn't have their own db profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the user via a logon trigger.  Have the trigger query the database for sessions belonging to the user.  If the user is already login error and log the present session out.

Comment: Thanks MichaelN, but I think the same problem as with Demage's answer ... fine if we are dealing with database users, but does not solve the OSSO/mid-tier problem because the users do not have a database session of their own.

Comment: SSO throws a wrench into that.  Can you make use of the Remote_User header to limit the number of similar user connection?